# File Descriptor passing with DBus to python client

Tags: python, c, linux, file-descriptor, dbus

I'm trying to access a **file descriptor** in python.

Further I'm using **gdbus-codegen** to generate my server side bindings and access methods then from a **python client**.

Basically invoking methods, passing normal parameters via GVariant Types and getting the return value in python works.

My application is centered around:

> https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/tests/gdbus-example-server.c

Invoking the method `GimmeStdout` I can't see the file descriptor returned simply as a return type. The file descriptor is returned as a `GUnixFDList` and I don't know how to access this in python.

I tried with own test methods and file file descriptors which are not `stdout`

So the question is: How do I access *UNIX_FD* transferred via DBus in python?